# Porque me tira error al querer borrar un trigger?

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion y estoy aprendiendo las funciones trigger en SQL Server. Puedo crear los triggers que quiera con laravel pero tengo problemas con borrarlos si existen:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'IF'. (SQL: DROP
>   TRIGGER IF EXISTS webmg_rank_week_character) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxis
>   incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'IF'. (SQL: DROP TRIGGER IF
>   EXISTS webmg_rank_week_character) at
>   C:\xampp\proyectos\index\engine\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664,
>   PDOException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra
>   clave 'IF'. at
>   C:\xampp\proyectos\index\engine\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:507)

El codigo que uso para crearlo es :

```
DB::unprepared('CREATE TRIGGER webmg_rank_week_character ON dbo.[Character]');
```

El codigo que uso para borrar es:

```
DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS webmg_rank_week_character');
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con este problema que no entiendo porque pasa, segun la syntax de SQL, se puede poner el IF EXISTS...

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que este problema se debe a que uso un SQL Server 2014 y la condicion IF EXISTS está disponible para version 2016 en adelante.

Solucione el problema cambiando el codigo

```
DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS webmg_rank_week_character');
```

Por el siguiente

```
DB::unprepared("IF (OBJECT_ID(N'[Character].[webmg_rank_week_character]') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
DROP TRIGGER [Character].[webmg_rank_week_character];
END");
```

---

**Actualizado**

En el codigo de laravel no es necesario introducir la base de datos, ya que, anteriormente se carga. Por lo que tambien puede funcionar de esta forma:

```
DB::unprepared("IF (OBJECT_ID(N'[webmg_rank_week_character]') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
DROP TRIGGER [webmg_rank_week_character];
END");
```

Espero les siva!

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, para indicar que está resuelto